# How to center loginStatus login screen

Tags: asp.net, css, authentication, loginstatus

I am trying to center the login control that shows after selecting login using the loginstatus control.

```
<div id="linkContent">
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus2" runat="server" 
        LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" />
</div>
```

I have tried a couple different methods that I found on google and none are working. I am using IE 9.

I tried:

```
#linkContent
{
text-align: center;
}
```

I have tried:

```
<div id="linkContent">
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus2" runat="server" 
        LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" style="text-align: center;" />
</div>
```

and I tried:

```
#linkContent
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

I also pointed login to my own Login.aspx but it doesn't work either:

in webconfig:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

None of these have worked. The login control stays left aligned. The loginStatus control is used within a master page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: give this a shot: http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 1):

Using inline style (move it to your CSS file!) :

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus2" runat="server" LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" />
</div>
```

Change 500px to the width of your control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto;` on the markup that the `LoginStatus` control generates, **not** the containing element.

Assuming you have [ClientIDMode="Static"](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40) in your `web.config`, and that the resulting HTML generated by the login static control will have an `id` of `LoginStatus2`, this will do the trick:

```
#LoginStatus2
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
```